# Figure in landscape mode is too small

Tags: floats, landscape

I have this figure which only fits in landscape mode. However, it my current settings it appears too small (see Figure). Can anyone help me maximi

[image: Figure is too small!]

I am using this code:

```
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{figure}[p]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{ch6/poaf_dt.pdf}
        \caption{Decision-tree used to predict postoperative atrial fibrillation.}
        \label{fig:poad_dt}
    \end{figure}
\end{landscape}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Use `width=\linewidth` and `height=.85\textwidth` (you need vertical space for the caption). Or you can load package `scrhack` and use `width=\textheight, height=.85\textwidth`.

Comment: It works :) can u please post this as an answer so that I mark it done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `landscape` environment you have to use eg `height=.9\textwidth` to ensure there is vertical space for the caption.

Unfortunaly you can not use `width=\textheight` because `landscape` changes it to the same value as `\textwidth`. So you have to use `width=\linewidth`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
Text
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{figure}[p]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=.9\textwidth
        %,keepaspectratio% commented for the example
        ]{example-image}
        \caption{Decision-tree used to predict postoperative atrial fibrillation.}
        \label{fig:poad_dt}
    \end{figure}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

With package `scrhack` you can use `width=\textheight` and showframe shows the correct page layout:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
Text
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{figure}[p]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textheight,height=.9\textwidth
        %,keepaspectratio% commented for the example
        ]{example-image}
        \caption{Decision-tree used to predict postoperative atrial fibrillation.}
        \label{fig:poad_dt}
    \end{figure}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]